# wikidata SPARQL query to determine if a thing is a museum exponate

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Let's say that I have a name. How can I write a sparql query to wikidata to determine if it is a museum exponate?

For example this query returns all the items on wikidata matching the name "The

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select ?thing 
where 
{ 
  ?thing rdfs:label "The Kiss"@en
}
```

One of this results will have the field `instance of` with value `monumental sculpture`. However, I may have another entry which is a painting. Is there another way to determine if given the name of an exponate it is indeed a museum exponate. Another that simply having the value of `instance of` field hardcoded locally along with the name of the exponate?

Comment: Perhaps `filter exists { ?thing wdt:P195 [] }`.

Comment: either that or following the location to any type of museum maybe? `PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select ?thing 
where 
{ 
  ?thing rdfs:label "The Kiss"@en ;
         wdt:P276/wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q33506
}` - maybe even a UNION of both? Might also be worth to check for diffs between both queries to find corner cases